# Customized Django SimpleJWT Views

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-framework-simplejwt

I am using a django-simplejwt and I have a custom token view for obtaining token. My problem is, how can i override the 401 Unauthorized response from the view?

https://django-rest-framework-simplejwt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/customizing_token_claims.html

```
from rest_framework_simplejwt.serializers import TokenObtainPairSerializer
from rest_framework_simplejwt.views import TokenObtainPairView

class ObtainTokenSerializer(TokenObtainPairSerializer):
    @classmethod
    def get_token(cls, user):
        token = super().get_token(user)


        # Add custom claims
        token['name'] = user.first_name
        # ...

        return token

class ObtainToken(TokenObtainPairView):
    serializer_class = ObtainTokenSerializer
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer might resides in the Exception raised.

As you dive in the simplejwt package you'd see something as following :

```
class InvalidToken(AuthenticationFailed):
    status_code = status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED
    default_detail = _('Token is invalid or expired')
    default_code = 'token_not_valid'
```

This is where comes from the 401 you see.

Therefore your class `ObtainToken` should override the post method from the mother class `TokenViewBase` with you specific `Exception` or `Response`.

For example :

```
from rest_framework import status
...

class ObtainToken(TokenObtainPairView):
    serializer_class = ObtainTokenSerializer
    ...
    def post(self, request):
        serializer = self.serializer_class(
            data=request.data, 
            context={'request': request}
        )

        try:
            serializer.is_valid()

            return Response(
                serializer.validated_data,
                status=status.HTTP_200_OK
            )
        except Exception:
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_404)
```

Although above is just an example, you should implement something similar as the post method from `TokenViewBase` but with your customized status and data.